# Infinite number of points in the Sierpinski Triangle

Tags: fractals

I have basic background in mathematics (Linear Algebra, Calculus) and I've been reading up on fractals, because I find them fascinating. I can't understand one thing in basically all of the fractals created using the iterated function systems.

For example, in the Sierpinski Triangle it can be easily shown using a limit, that after an infinity of iterations there will be nothing left of the triangle, and yet I will still have an infinite number of points. The same thing happens with Cantor's Comb, etc. How can I remove all of the area and still have an infinite number of points?

Could you help me understand this? Please keep in mind that I'm not very proficient in mathematical logic.

Thanks,

Comment: The Sierpinski triangle certainly contains a line segment, so there's infinitely many points right there.

Answer (score 1):

It can sound a little confusing at first, but remember that there are also infinitely many points in a line, that doesn't have any area either.

Comment: That's absolutely right, but consider Cantor's Comb - a line which has one third removed in each iteration leaving two copies. This time after infinite iterations the line is completely gone (simple limit), but still it has infinite points. It is gone, but I have an infinite number of points (and there was no area at the beginning, nor the end). How can I remove everything and still have an infinite number of points?

Comment: You didn't remove everything! You didn't remove $1$. Or $1/3$. Or $1/9$. Or $1/27$. Or *any* number of the form $1/3^k$.